# what is <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true">?

Tags: xml, exception, nullpointerexception

When I run program I receive this error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acau7.png

```
Time out.Bytes not found
```

Inside folder `C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\SPOON\CACHE\0xCD27F35E6D57DCAA\sxs\Manifests` I have this files

```
_VideoConverter.exe_0x6a91ee5efb16896ba86a5942f951668f.1.manifest
Movavi.io.dll_0xc16fe9d9f683ef0c3ccd5a2c82a5f19f.2.manifest
MovaviTracker.dll_0x7b548ea141dc5ea1fe03fee6e585f8a1.2.manifest
```

Inside of _videoConverter, for example I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false">
        </requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

but if I change to

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true">
```

error `Time out` no longer occurs.
**Why ?** What happens ?

Answer (score 5):

Any exe that has UIAccess set to true needs to be signed and stored in a secure location, for example C:\Program Files.. etc.

So when you change the value in the manifest file you will be preventing the program from running - so no timeout.